# rviz-for-android

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi guys,

I´m working in a project in which i have to run rviz in a tablet. I´m using (http://www.willowgarage.com/blog/2012/09/24/rviz-android-0) app. But in the app i don't received any date.

i'm working with indigo and ubuntu 14.04. i'm trying the next steps:

1. i run my simulation in rviz in my pc to show if my program show something.
2. i run server.py
3. i run tf_throttle that the app required.

and to finish i run the app of rviz on my tablet.

the app ask me for a ip. we try doing it by wifi connection. We make netstat to show if the connection is working or not and in the state it say is established but no dates are sending or receiving.

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State

tcp        0      0 192.168.8.1:53803       192.168.8.10:49342      ESTABLISHED

In the app in the status of a display that is working in the rviz of the pc say No PointCloud messages received.

what could i try to make the application work?

thanks very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203675/rviz-for-android/) by [zior89](https://answers.ros.org/users/13176/zior89/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This could be a classic ROS-on-Android network configuration issue. See:

- [Network configuration ros <--> android_core](http://answers.ros.org/question/44211/network-configuration-ros-android_core/)
- [Android subscriber can get msg but "rostopic echo" cannot?](http://answers.ros.org/question/197034/android-subscriber-can-get-msg-but-rostopic-echo-cannot/)
- [Node on RosAndroid is not receiving images from PC.](http://answers.ros.org/question/200400/node-on-rosandroid-is-not-receiving-images-from-pc/)

for some other questions about this.

In short: make sure that you either have a properly setup DNS (where both your Android device and your ROS master can resolve each other's hostnames), or force the ROS master to use bare IPs for everything, using appropriate values for `ROS_IP` and `ROS_MASTER_URI`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0